# Failed building boost for GCC on Win10

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, jam, boost-build

I'm trying to build b2 from bootstrap.bat with gcc. It exists with the following:

> C:\Program Files\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2>bootstrap gcc
>
> Bootstrapping the build engine
>
> execnt.c:31: tlhelp32.h: No such file or directory
>
> filent.c: In function `file_dirscan': filent.c:84: storage size of `finfo' isn't known
>
> filent.c:175: `_A_SUBDIR' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> filent.c:175: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>
> filent.c:175: for each function it appears in.)
>
> jam.c: In function `main':
>
> jam.c:425: `environ'undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> jam.c:425: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>
> jam.c:425: for each function it appears in.)
>
> Failed to bootstrap the build engine
>
> Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.

The log doesn't say too much either:

> ###
>
> ### Using 'gcc' toolset.
>
> ###
>
> C:\Program Files\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2\engine>if exist bootstrap
>   rd /S /Q bootstrap
>
> C:\Program Files\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2\engine>md bootstrap
>
> C:\Program Files\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2\engine>gcc -DNT -o
>   bootstrap\jam0.exe  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execnt.c
>   filent.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c
>   jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c
>   pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c
>   variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c pwd.c
>   class.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c
>   modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c
>   modules/order.c

Obviously no b2 is built. What does all this mean, and how could it be solved?

Comment: `execnt.c:31: tlhelp32.h: No such file or directory `: the first part is part of a C or C++ compiler's diagnostics, while the text is a Windows command interpreter's diagnostic. That's nonsense to me. It seems you have a fouled up installation package.

Comment: tlhelp32.h is part of MS Tool Help Library. No idea what gcc would make of that, even if it could find it.

Comment: I also suspected that the source that I downloaded is damaged, so I tried building the 1_66_0 version. It doesn't get much further: after the errors in jam.c, it encounters syntax errors in timestamp.c before exiting with the "Failed to bootstrap the build engine" message. 

The batch file from the 1_53_0 version defaulted to Visual Studio compiler, that I don't have. However 1_66_0 could be ran without specifying any compiler, and it successfully built the exe. I still don't know why it didn't work before, but this work-around solved the issue.